# With GlobalProtect VPN I need to retry many times before connecting successfully

Tags: networking, vpn, macos-ventura

I am using macOS Ventura 13.1 (M1 Pro CPU) with GlobalProtect VPN 6.1.0-58. Once I establish the VPN connection it is stable and it's working fine. But the process of establishing the connection is very frustrating. My GlobalProtect client gets stuck for some time and then it just fails to connect. Then after 5 to 10 minutes of desperate random combinations of killing and restarting GlobalProtect process, clicking "Refresh Connection" button and signing out and signing in again in GlobalProtect settings it usually succeeds in the end. Sometimes it even takes more than 10 minutes and it's very annoying and frustrating. I depend on GlobalProtect and I must use it so the answers such as "Try another VPN" are just not helpful.

I also noticed that when I downgrade to GlobalProtect 5.2 it's working fine and it connects normally but the problem is that GlobalProtect updates automatically in the background and I can't find an option to disable automatic updates. Is there an option to do that?

Any other proposal which doesn't include downgrading GlobalProtect?

Comment: …and have you approached the developers about the issue with their application?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what was the issue and how to overcome it. When we initiate establishing a VPN connection via GlobalProtect client, the app will redirect you to your browser to complete an SSO authentication. After completing the authentication, depending on which browser you use, you will get the popup prompt "Do you want to allow this page to open GlobalProtect.app?"

If you get this popup prompt, you should click allow, then the trick is to wait for about 10 seconds for another same page to appear as well as the same popup prompt, then you click "allow" again and you will be connected.

If you browser doesn't show this popup, then it will display this message on a web page "Please click Open GlobalProtect if you see the system dialog. If nothing prompts from browser, click here to launch GlobalProtect".

You should manually click this link, then you should also wait for some 10 seconds until the same page is opened automatically in a new tab and then you should manually click on the same link again. You will be immediately connected then.

This might sound unnecessarily complicated and to be honest I don't know why this works this way but anyway what I described above is reliable deterministic step by step tutorial how to normally use VPN with GlobalProtect.